# shiny: how to add a reactive bar in shiny app

Tags: javascript, html, shiny, shinyjs

I am building a crowd funding shiny app that tracks how much donation has been given. Is there such a function that creates a reactive bar in shiny? If not, is it possible to do this in html,css,javascript?

I would like to create something like this:

[image]

Comment: it is possible as long as you have reactive dataset! Sample code will be usefull!

Comment: @Malvina_a I already have a reactive dataset. My question is how can I create something like the picture above by using shiny functions, html, css, etc.

Comment: I have understood the question, but eitherway it is always good to create sample app with sample data, so someone who would like to help you, can easily do it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have two solutions for You:

**(1)** I can recommend You to use the `gauge` from `flexdashboard package`, it is not a bar but for the purpose of Yours can be fine..

**Sample App:**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(flexdashboard)


ui <- basicPage(flexdashboard::gaugeOutput("plt1"))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  output$plt1 <- flexdashboard::renderGauge({
    gauge(15399, min = 0, max = 20000, symbol = '$', label = paste("Test Label"),gaugeSectors(
      success = c(15000,20000), warning = c(15000,1000), danger = c(0, 1000)))

  })
})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

**(2)** This function helps You to create bar (taken from [github](https://github.com/rstudio/shinydashboard/issues/119))

**Sample App:**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

prgoressBar <- function(value = 0, label = FALSE, color = "aqua", size = NULL,
                        striped = FALSE, active = FALSE, vertical = FALSE) {
  stopifnot(is.numeric(value))
  if (value < 0 || value > 100)
    stop("'value' should be in the range from 0 to 100.", call. = FALSE)
  if (!(color %in% shinydashboard:::validColors || color %in% shinydashboard:::validStatuses))
    stop("'color' should be a valid status or color.", call. = FALSE)
  if (!is.null(size))
    size <- match.arg(size, c("sm", "xs", "xxs"))
  text_value <- paste0(value, "%")
  if (vertical)
    style <- htmltools::css(height = text_value, `min-height` = "2em")
  else
    style <- htmltools::css(width = text_value, `min-width` = "2em")
  tags$div(
    class = "progress",
    class = if (!is.null(size)) paste0("progress-", size),
    class = if (vertical) "vertical",
    class = if (active) "active",
    tags$div(
      class = "progress-bar",
      class = paste0("progress-bar-", color),
      class = if (striped) "progress-bar-striped",
      style = style,
      role = "progressbar",
      `aria-valuenow` = value,
      `aria-valuemin` = 0,
      `aria-valuemax` = 100,
      tags$span(class = if (!label) "sr-only", text_value)
    )
  )
}

progressGroup <- function(text, value, min = 0, max = value, color = "aqua") {
  stopifnot(is.character(text))
  stopifnot(is.numeric(value))
  if (value < min || value > max)
    stop(sprintf("'value' should be in the range from %d to %d.", min, max), call. = FALSE)
  tags$div(
    class = "progress-group",
    tags$span(class = "progress-text", text),
    tags$span(class = "progress-number", sprintf("%d / %d", value, max)),
    prgoressBar(round(value / max * 100), color = color, size = "sm")
  )
}

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(disable = TRUE),
  dashboardBody(uiOutput("plt1")))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

output$plt1 <- renderUI({progressGroup(text = "A", value = 15399, min = 0, max = 20000, color = "green")
  })
})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: money<- 0
observeEvent(input$click_counter, {   
    money<- money+500
}
output$plt1 <- renderGauge({
    gauge(money, min = 0, max = 20000, symbol = '$', label = paste("donation"),gaugeSectors(
      success = c(15000,20000), warning = c(15000,1000), danger = c(0, 1000)))
  })

Comment: I am sorry for the bad formatting of my code above, but do you know how to make the number in the gauge to change dynamically every time the input$click_counter is clicked?

Comment: I would recommend to use `reactiveValues()` for money